# Temp variable not assigning right value from array

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino, arduino-ide, temp

I am writing a program on the arduino IDE where i want to swap some variables around. If you are unaware of arduino, it is essentially written in C++.

A bit of background information:

- Pieces is a 2D array
- Pieces will return a string of "n", "1", "2", ..., "5", or "6"
- Serial.println(msg) is just a print function

Here is the code:

```
String temp = Pieces[piece][0];
Serial.println(temp);
Serial.println(Pieces[piece][0]);
```

The code should return 2 of the same values, but what it actually returns is:

```
""
"n"
```

The first value should be n as well, but it is just blank. Here is how Pieces was initialised:

```
String Pieces[27][6] =
  {
    {"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n"},
    {"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n"},
    {"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n"},
    {"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n"},
    {"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n"},
    {"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n"},
    {"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n"},
    {"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n"},
    {"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n"},
    {"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n"},
    {"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n"},
    {"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n"},
    {"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n"},
    {"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n"},
    {"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n"},
    {"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n"},
    {"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n"},
    {"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n"},
    {"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n"},
    {"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n"},
    {"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n"},
    {"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n"},
    {"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n"},
    {"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n"},
    {"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n"},
    {"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n"},
    {"t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t"}
  };
```

The problem is that the array is too large, so i've tried to change it to chars instead of strings, but its not working.

Heres what it looks like now:

```
char Pieces[27][6] =
 {
    {"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n"},
    {"n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n"},
    ...
    {"t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t"}
 };
```

And heres the error its giving me:

```
error: too many initializers for 'char [6]'
```

Could someone help me to initialize it properly?

Comment: how is `piece` set and what are the bounds of the `Pieces` array dimensions?

Comment: I've edited the question so it shows what Pieces looks like, I hope thats enough information for you to know where im coming from

Comment: The code seems to be fine. Did you rule out other factors, like out-of-memory problem or serial interface problem? Did you try with smaller array? Did you try with single-dimensional array?

Comment: The arduino IDE states that:
Sketch uses 8292 bytes (25%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 1314 bytes (64%) of dynamic memory, leaving 734 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
So i believe the memory is fine.

I will go and test on other arrays and see how that turns out

Comment: I shortened the array to 8 elements and things seem to work fine like that. Would the only workaround be to break the array up into smaller arrays?

Comment: You can dclare the Pieces array as const PROGMEM, if you do not need to modify them runtime. Otherwise you can save memory by not using String type. use char if you only need one character, or char array if you need more.

Comment: @MarekFekete The array needs to be constantly modified, so const PROGMEM isnt an option. i'm trying to convert it to an array of chars but its not working... info back in the question.

Comment: Chars should be enclosed in apostrophes, `'n'`

Comment: **char with double-quote** ???

Comment: Yep i changed the double quotes to single and everything is fine now. Sorry i'm used to python where double quotes and single quotes do the same thing. Thanks for all the help guys :)

Oh and the memory usage went from 64% to 21% when i started using chars, so thanks for that as well ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems to be a memory-related problem, you should consider using simple `char`s instead of `String`s, or `char[]` if you really need multi-character strings.

Your initialization would then look like this:

```
char Pieces[][6] =
 {
    {'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n'},
    {'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n', 'n'},
    ...
    {'t', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't'}
 };
```

and your assignment would be

```
char temp = Pieces[piece][0];
```

In case you need to use strings, use char*:

```
char* Pieces[][6] =
    {
        { "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n" },
        ...
        { "n", "n", "n", "n", "n", "n" }
    };

char *temp = Pieces[0][1];
```

If you are not going to perform any fancy string operations, the `String` class is not useful for you anyhow.

By the way, note how conveniently you can leave out the array size when initializing.